# Angular 4: inverse relation between: Componentizing HTML, and how complex it is to pass variables to relevant siblings?

Tags: angular

I was wondering if I'm thinking wrong about this.

I would like to think that making as many sub-components on an HTML page would be considered a good practice.

Take this case, for example:

StuffComponent is refactored into components of set: {StuffFilterPanelComponent,StuffContentDisplayComponent}.

Based on the filters specified in the filter panel section, this sets certain booleans/flags that are to be used to conditionally modify how things display in StuffContentDisplayComponent.

Yet, since the filter panel section is a sibling component of "stuffContentDisplay", I would go about using a Service and EventEmitter to keep the ContentDisplay aware of the flags set in the FilterPanel section.  This introduces so much added code complexity in comparison to when I wouldn't have broken StuffComponent into 2 sub-components.

Is there always going to be this rather significant tradeoff between ease of data-sharing and level of Componentization?  It seems that the Angular framework to some extent is discouraging breaking code into very granular components, unless I'm not doing something correctly in Angular.

Is there a better way of doing things, or is this just an unavoidable part of the Angular framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use @input and @output. Depending on your configuration, it may be an easier way to pass values/flags from a parent component to its children.

See the docs here for more information: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I've used Input to pass from parent to child component, but for some reason in the examples I've seen, Output is only used to deal with event emitters. So If the data is an attribute of one child, then there wouldn't be a way to send it to the other child with just the Output, leave use of the event emitter. Unless I'm misinterpreting.

Comment: Everything would have to come from the parent. So the child with the attribute would need to notify the parent which in turn would notify the other children. This seems less interwoven then each child communicating with other children.   Or you could go with the prior suggestion and use a service with each child getting values and setting values in the service.

Comment: Right.  I had that figured as such, but that would kindof go against the whole point of encapsulating the variable into the component in which it "belongs to the most" (instead of setting it in the parent and pushing it down into each component that sets/gets the data).  I'm new to Angular and just trying to figure out the best practice in regards to this.  So maybe it's fine to travel up the tree to the joining parent Component and then down to the other child component that needs the data.  Was just trying to get things sorted in my mind as to what other people think of the topic.

Comment: Thanks for that documentation page.  Helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the extent you go for this type of things.

Yes you'd want a service.

Here is what I'd do:

- Distribute your current component in how many components you want. I like small ones.
- Have one general service that acts as a mediator for those components. So each time they want to comunicate they do so via the service. This doesn't add much complexity honnestly. You can even change things directly from the template.
- If you need to communicate with the outside world from this component, then EventEmitter will be ybetter

So in this case you have multiple component and one service holding the value needed for those multiple components. In my opinion this is a win, good separation, not a lot of complexity added (I'd argue there is less).

If you'd go to the extreme opposite you'd have your whole app in a single component, but that wouldn't be manageable, would it ?

---

Some people don't stop there however. There is a philosophy that your components must be the dumbest they can, so they are easily reusable (even though you'll rarely reuse them). The idea is that if you have a component that you'd want to reuse, then use `EventEmitter` so each component is self contained and you can reuse them pretty much anywhere else (without need for the associated service). If the tree of component is above 2 in depth imo what happens is a rise in complexity, decrease in readability for an hypothetical reusability that will most likely not be there.

In practice, however, you kinda know at what level a component of yours will be reusable and you can design it as such without strictly following the above guideline.